# \2 mean in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

As of my understanding \2 represents the contents of group 2.

So, the expression `r'(\w*)(\w)\2'` should return the contents of group2( i.e `\w`)
but when we use the word having repeated characters it is returning repeated characters.
example:

```
re.search(r'(\w*)(\w)\2','finally').group(2) -> 'l'
re.search(r'(\w*)(\w)\2','finallyy').group(2) ->'y'
```

In the 1st example the output is 'l' instead of 'y'.

Can anyone tell me what exactly \2 mean in regular expression and where does my understanding is wrong.

Comment: It thus means that the character in the second group is repeated. So this matches string where a character is repeated *two times* (or more).

Comment: `\2` means the second capturing group - `(\w)`. The given pattern searches for a string followed by repeated letters. So, `\1` matches `fina` and `\2` matches `ll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "*reference*" to the second capture group. It thus means that the content in the second capture group is repeated.

For example with this regex, `'finally'` and `'finallyy'` are matched as:

```
(\w*) (\w) \2    <rest>
fina   l   l     y
finall y   y
```

Since the *Kleene star* is greedy, it will typically eat as much characters as possible, but still matching the string.

So in short if the second capture group would match `foo`, then `\2` has to be able to match `foo` as well.

Strictly speaking such constructs are *not always* regular expressions (at least not in the strict mathematical sense): regular expressions can only match *regular languages*, and regular languages should be parseable by a *finite state machine*. If the second group for example can match an arbitrary number of characters (for example with `(\w+)\1`), then one can not encode this on a finite state machine.